# Grammar, language

Tags: grammaire, expressions, vocabulaire

Today at my French class we had a little exercise;  we should continue a dialogue  and here it is:

> Qu'est-ce que tu écoutes à la radio ?

> C'est une émission qui parle des évènements sociaux.

Here I wanted to talk about "émission" specifically. So should I say

> Est-ce qu'il a parlé de tous les évènements en détail ?

Or le pronom "il" here is a mistake?

Comment: traiter d'un sujet: Il s’agit de la chaîne d’information radio dédiée à des thématiques économiques et financières. L’ensemble des **émissions traite de sujets** liés à l’actualité économique. https://www.citeco.fr/%C3%A9missions-%C3%A9conomiques-fran%C3%A7aises

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is fine except the pronoun used. ***Émission*** being a feminine noun (*une émission*), you should use ***elle***:

> Est-ce qu'**elle** a parlé de tous les évènements en détail?

<sub><sub>A side off-topic note about the second sentence:</sub>

  <sub>***C'est** une émission qui parle des évènements sociaux.*</sub>

<sub>***C'est*** is not needed here. A more logical answer to "*Qu'est-ce que tu écoutes à la radio ?*" would be:</sub>

  <sub>***Une** émission qui parle des évènements sociaux.*</sub></sub>

Comment: For neatness this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130008/discussion-on-answer-by-dimitris-grammar-language).